Apparent impossibility for spherically symmetric wormhole throats to be devoid of horizons
On Matt Visser's Lorentzian Wormholes there is a brief discussion of "topologically trivial" wormholes, also known as baby universes, or Bag of Gold spacetimes by some authors. This image makes the concept clear:

A few months ago, I started to investigate a bit more on details on this geometry. Surprisingly I couldn't find any paper working out the basic physics of this type of spacetime.
Clearly one can always write down the geometry and just assert that the $T_{\mu \nu}$ is whatever would have the EFE satisfied. This however is a very unsatisfying approach, and I would like to treat the specifics of geometry as an output, rather than an input.
If one writes down the most general static spherically symmetric spacetime, one has the following metric:
$$ ds^2 = - \Phi(r) dt^2 + \Lambda(r) dr^2 + \Omega(r) d\Omega^2 $$
with $ d\Omega^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin(\theta)^2 d\phi$.
And the most general static spherically symmetric stress-matter tensor would be:
$$ T^{\mu}_{\nu} = - \rho(r) \delta^{\mu}_0 \delta^0_{\nu} + p_R(r) \delta^{\mu}_1 \delta^1_{\nu} + p_T(r) ( \delta^{\mu}_2 \delta^2_{\nu} + \delta^{\mu}_3 \delta^3_{\nu} ) $$
With $\rho(r), p_R(r), p_T(r)$ being respectively the density, the radial pressure and the tangential pressure.
Now, is very standard practice to "wave away" the $\Omega(r)$ function and sweep it under some radial parametrization. While this might be indeed a valid process in a vacuum (as shown by this answer), it is not legitimate to do this in a BoG geometry, as the throat is a region of nonzero minimal area. Even previous analysis of Visser and Wheeler regarding Lorentzian wormholes use this radial parametrization, however they are already assuming a surgery of Minkowski spacetimes at the throat, so it already assumes a non-trivial topology, and I'm interested in the topologically trivial case.
As a matter of fact, I think we can agree we can define in purely local terms a throat as a region for which $\Omega'(r) = 0$, or equivalently, one for which spherical area is minimal.
When we work the equation for $G_{00} - \kappa T_{00} = 0$ we reach the following equation for $\Lambda(r)$
$$ \left(- \kappa \Omega{\left(r \right)} \rho{\left(r \right)} + 1\right) \Lambda^{2}{\left(r \right)} + \left(- \frac{d^{2}}{d r^{2}} \Omega{\left(r \right)}
 + \frac{\left(\frac{d}{d r} \Omega{\left(r \right)}\right)^{2}}{4 \Omega{\left(r \right)}}\right) \Lambda{\left(r \right)} + \frac{\frac{d}{d r} \left(\Lambda{\left(r \right)}\right) \frac{d}{d r} \Omega{\left(r \right)}}{2} = 0$$
Given the factor $\frac{d}{dr} \Omega(r)$ next to $\frac{d}{dr}\Lambda(r)$, we suspect this equation might become ill-defined close to a throat (a region where $\Omega'(r) = 0$)
With the help of CAS software, one can find a general solution to this equation:
$$ \Lambda{\left(r \right)} = \frac{\left(\frac{d}{d r} \Omega{\left(r \right)}\right)^{2}}{C_{1} \sqrt{\Omega{\left(r \right)}} - 2 \kappa \sqrt{\Omega{\left(
r \right)}}  \int \{ \sqrt{\Omega{\left(r \right)}} \rho{\left(r \right)} \frac{d}{d r} \Omega{\left(r \right)}\, \} dr + 4 \Omega{\left(r \right)}} $$
Two things stand out inmediately from this solution:

The radial coordinate seems to collapse at the throat
Looking at the gravitational mass integral in the denominator, one sees that the sign of $\Omega'(r)$ determines also the sign of mass! so positive mass crossing the throat would seems as becoming gravitationally negative

Since I've assumed very little else, not even assuming any form of energy condition must hold whatsoever, this solution might seem to rule out a traversable, horizon-free Bag of Gold "wormhole", even with "exotic matter"
Note: CAS software can also handle the solution for $\Phi(r)$ from $G_{11} - \kappa T_{11}=0$, but they are much more unwieldly to include here, nonetheless doing a few numerical experiments it seems to always diverge at the throat.
The question now boils down to: Is the above analysis conclusive? Is there are way to avoid an horizon forming at (or near) the throat? Is possible that this is just one of those annoying and confusing coordinate singularities?
Of more broader interest would be this question: Seems that the procedure of first postulating a metric, then finding out what matter distribution would lead to this metric is incorrect in certain cases, as we are clearly reaching a different conclusion than previous papers have.

It is not clear to me what you mean by “the radial coordinate seems to collapse at the throat”.
If you are referring to the fact that the metric becomes degenerate because $\Lambda (r) = 0$ at the throat, this is a known fact and is due to a bad choice of coordinates as can be read in Section 3 of the Morris and Thorne paper.
In fact, taking their well-known metric of a wormhole
\begin{equation}
d s^2=  -e^{2 \Phi} c^2 d t^2+\frac{d r^2}{(1-b(r)/r)} + r^2\left(d \theta^2+\sin^2 \theta d \phi^2\right),
\end{equation}
the radial component of the metric at the throat $b(r_0) = r_0$ becomes ill defined, and it is necessary to resort to the proper radial distance, which in your case $dl = \pm \sqrt{\Lambda(r)} \, dr$ brings the metric to
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = -\Phi(l) dt^2 +dl^2 + \Omega(l) d\Omega^2
\end{equation}
where $\Phi(l) = \Phi(r(l))$ and $\Omega(l) = \Omega(r(l))$. To answer your question then yes, it is one of those coordinate singularities.

I already mentioned my issue with this briefly in the MQ, but to clarify: this is an entirely different geometry, the throat is given ad-hoc, does not arise by matter-induced curvature in any meaningful sense. So it doesn't help me to understand how or why would a throat be sustained or form in the first place in a topologically trivial spacetime

If it is indeed a bad choice of coordinates, the symptom should be a finite non-zero determinant $g$ everywhere, correct? and a change toward better coordinates should be possible without writing a new metric from scratch with new boundary conditions at the throat.

I think I should give additional clarification on what I mean with "does not arise by matter-induced curvature in any meaningful sense": There is a mismatch between simply postulating a topology (throat at $b(r_0) = r_0$) and solving EFE given the background topology, and starting from trivial topology and reaching the throat geometry as a possible solution. I think this latter one is to be preferred. After that, this is the gist of the BoG

There is no change in topology. Spatial topology remains trivial in the case expressed by Visser, and that is precisely the point. Despite the development of the “umbilical cord” that mimics the formation of a wormhole the spatial topology remains $\mathbb{R}^3$.


The radial coordinate seems to collapse at the throat

There is no “collapse” (and no horizon necessary in such solution) because expression for $\Lambda$ is an indeterminate form of $0/0$ type rather than zero. It is a consequence of invariance of the metric under the change of coordinate $r\to r'=f(r)$. Under that transformation $ Λ$ changes, so that $ Λ dr =  Λ' dr'$. It means that under a suitable transformation  $Λ$ could be
anything, and Einstein equations alone do not fix it. This freedom could be eliminated by a suitable “gauge fixing” condition, the simplest of which compatible with a “bag of gold” static universe would be $ Λ
 =1$.

Seems that the procedure of first postulating a metric, then finding out what matter distribution would lead to this metric is incorrect in certain cases...

General relativity has built in general covariance. This means that sometimes Einstein equations produce underdetermined system, which must then be supplemented by a suitable choice of gauge fixing condition.

Hi! I'm struggling to verify the assertion that $\Lambda$ becomes indeterminate when $\Omega'(r) = 0$, why would the integral in the denominator become zero?

I would recommend 1) using better parametrization for the metric (so that square roots do not appear) 2) start with a series expansion at the “bottleneck” and solve for all coefficients of that expansion using a small set of parameters. Substitute expansions into actual Einstein equations, do not try to shoehorn CAS provided solution. The result should be that all expansion coefficients for $g_{rr}$ can be chosen completely arbitrarily.
